# Could not download javapoet.jar (com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0): No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After updating my Android Studio to the latest version, i get the following error while building my project:

## Could not download javapoet.jar (com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0): No cached version available for offline mode

Comment: jcenter is having issues. http://status.bintray.com/

Comment: I am facing same issue .How you resolved this.kindly share

Comment: Adding mavenCentral() in build.gradle solved for me

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
}